# window.location.reload(); reloads page uncontrollably?

Tags: jquery, json

can anybody explain why this is? here my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    refresh();
});

function refresh()
{      
    $.getJSON('getMessageDetails.php', function (json) {
        //alert(json.length);
        //$("#subject1").html(json[0].subject);
        //$("#unique_code1").html(json[0].unique_code);  
        $("#msg_id").html(json[0].id);
        $("#subject").html(json[0].subject);
        $("#unique_code").html(json[0].unique_code);  
        if (json.length > 0 )
        {
            //alert(json.length);
            window.location.reload(); 
        }     
        else
        {
            //do something
        } 
    }); 
    window.setTimeout(refresh,30000);
}
</script>
```

What I am trying to do is if a new message came in json wont be empty so reload the page and if there are no new messages, keep on checking

What happens now is a new message comes in and the screen just starts flashing like crazy! 
It must do the reload once and then every 30 seconds check again. Any help please? Thank you.

Comment: And where is a definitions of function refresh from window.setTimeout? also window.location.reload(); should be run from window.setTimeout

Comment: i posted full script at the top :)

Comment: If it's still flashing you json.length is probably greater 0 ?

Comment: The code you posted does not seem to cause such a thing.. what's the "do something" code?

Comment: "do something" will be coded later thus the else part is empty..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for `setInterval` instead as it sound like you want to call your function every 30 seconds instead of reloading the whole page (that's what `window.location.reload`does).

Example:

```
function sayHello(){
alert('hello once again');
}
setInterval(sayHello,30000);
```

So what you have to do is wrap your AJAX call in a function and then apply a `setInterval` that defines when it gets repeated.

Comment: i want to reload the whole page(as if refresh button was clicked) but ONLY when json.length > 0, thus a new message has come in, and also check for new messages every 30000 :)

Comment: Can you describe the "flashing" then if it does not seem to be a reload?

Comment: all i know is this keeps on executing window.location.reload(); so fast that the screen goes blank and it doesnt stop..i have to close the page

Comment: Does `window.location.reload();` appear elsewhere in your code?

Comment: Well then this has to be the root of all evil (try commenting it out for a start). Also have you tried using the approach in the other answer, using an interval instead of timeout yet? Is your AJAX-call returning a proper result?

Comment: ha ha yes, but i will rather do timeout because it is for a mobile site.. i have commented it out and not going to bother any further but thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var int = setInterval(refresh,30000);
});

function refresh()
{      
$.getJSON('getMessageDetails.php', function (json) {
 //alert(json.length);
 //$("#subject1").html(json[0].subject);
 //$("#unique_code1").html(json[0].unique_code);  
 $("#msg_id").html(json[0].id);
 $("#subject").html(json[0].subject);
 $("#unique_code").html(json[0].unique_code);  
 if (json.length > 0 )
 {
    //alert(json.length);
    window.location.reload(); 
 }     
 else
 {
    //do something
 } 
 }); 

 }
```